# Replace Fragment with Button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to replace a fragment with a button. Basically I have this form (which is all the input views on helloFragment) and I want to click submit and show the form information on the next fragment (showFormFragment).

It renders the first fragment on my device, but the button won't replace it. It doesn't crash however.

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:name="teaminfamous.com.fragments.helloFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_hello">
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My onCreate and Button listner:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        helloFragment hf = new helloFragment();
        FormShow fs = new FormShow();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, hf);

        Button submitbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        submitbtn.setOnClickListener(submitForm);

    }
```

EDIT:

In Fragment Class helloFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_form_show, container, false);
    Button submitbtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    submitbtn.setOnClickListener(submitForm);


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
private View.OnClickListener submitForm = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do handling here
        final EditText nameField = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
        final EditText originField = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.originEdit);
        String name = nameField.getText().toString();
        String origin = nameField.getText().toString();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        FormShow show = new FormShow();
        ft.replace(R.id.hello, show, show.toString() ).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        //final TextView nameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameShow);
        // nameText.setText(name);
    }

};
```

I hit submit and the onClickListner gets called and it shows a blank screen now

I'm pretty new to Android and a novice in Java, so an explanation for the usual pattern for doing something like this would also be helpful.

Comment: Where are `R.id.nameEdit`. `R.id.originEdit`,  and `R.id.submitButton`?

Comment: those are in the fragment's layouts.

Comment: Then that `View.OnClickListener` should go inside the fragment class. If you need to comunicate with the activity then you should do it through an interface to the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to change your

```
  <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:name="teaminfamous.com.fragments.helloFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_hello">
  </fragment>
```

to `<FrameLayout>`
Then, instead of this code:

```
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, hf);
```

use

```
ft.replace(R.id.hello, hf).commit();
```

and it should work

Comment: yeah I saw an example like that but then it showed up with just a blank screen but ill try again! Is there a reason why it has to be a FrameLayout?

Comment: ended up with a Fatal Error something about my onClickListner button I'm assuming it can't find my button because the layout won't render it :/

Comment: yes, because right now, you need to get this button in fragment class(onCreateView)

Comment: yup its my button listener. It only works if I comment out this line         `submitbtn.setOnClickListener(submitForm);`
from my `onCreate` method.

Comment: transfer your code with button to fragment onCreateView(). It's should do the trick

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "get this button" are you talking about doing the onClickListener in my onCreateView in it's respective fragment class?

Comment: activity doesn't have this code now, fragment does. In your FormShow fragment you should override onCreateView, inflate your layout there into View, and get this button from it, then set it on click listner and do ither stuff

Comment: ahh I see I just tried it in the wrong fragment class. I'll try this out and let you know thanks alot!

Comment: Alright tried that but now main Activity doesn't seem to see it but I thought there, I know Im messing something up I updated the current code in the post. I overrode onCreateView and had the button listener there so it'd swap the fragment and inflate the view. Or am I get that process wrong?

Comment: you should go  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_form_show, container, false); The use it as getView() you're currently using, and return thus view instead of inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_form_show, container, false);

Comment: i think im starting to understand. return that getView() instead in my formshow fragment. but leave my buttons in main. hmmm i'll probably have to do some reading cause now i dont see how some of this works.

Comment: no, you wont return getView(), you'll return view, which you'll create, you've been given inflater to inflater view in your made View param and return it, for activity to know which view you want to have

Comment: I see the confusion my formshow is suppose to only show data captured by hello fragment. but my hello fragment is the actual form. I moved my stuff there and it returns a blank screen but it does switch to the fragment!

Comment: but do you have in the end? Is there any issue again?

Comment: it switches to a blank screen trying to verify if its the new fragment but i see how i wasnt understanding somethings you helped me through that so ill accept the answer. pretty sure it is the new fragment.

Answer (score 2):

In order to replace fragment dynamically you have to add it at runtime. To do this you need a container that will host your fragment e.g. FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Then you need an access the FragmentManager to begin transaction:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
String tag = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
transaction.replace( R.id.fragment_container, new YourFragmentHere(), tag);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: same thing as Nik Myers said then? or does the tag add a huge difference?

Comment: Sure. tag is optional. Here is a great tutorial about adding fragments statistically vs dynamically http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#usingfragments_layout

Comment: awesome I'll def check it out! Thank you!